# How do I migrate my private key from one device to another in instant messaging app?

Tags: security, encryption, end-to-end

I was thinking about end-to-end encryption for my chat application, but I am struggling to understand how do I migrate my private keys from one device to another.

One option I thought is to store private keys somewhere very secure (which I can't imagine of), but it will expose the privacy...

Another option is to do something with the password to encrypt messages...

Is there anyone who can help with or make any suggestions how to implement end-to-end encryption with a possibility for users to start using same app on another device or similar?

Comment: The whole idea behind public-key cryptography that you can exchange public keys with another party and use them to encrypt data (in this case, messages) that can only be decrypted with the associated private key. Why would you ever transfer your private keys?

Comment: In any case, while I won't pass judgment on the on-topicness of this question for Stack Overflow, you might find it more beneficial to delete this question and instead post it on SO's sister [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: @esqew, thanks. What if used Device A, and now I want to use Device B. And all data is encrypted using private key from device a... What should I do?

Comment: I mean encrypted using public key from device a. How can I decrypt it on device b?

Comment: The standard technique is to use password-based encryption to export the private key in encrypted form, move it to the new device, and import it into the new device, supplying the same password used in the export process.

Comment: @JamesKPolk, that's a good answer.

Comment: What happens if the device is lost?